# Removal of XML empty tags using XSLT

Tags: xslt

Need xslt to get the below expected output xml.

My Input :

```
<accounts>
   <Customer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="text_type" name="customername"><value></value></Customer>
   <Customer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="text_type" name="customernumber"><value>101</value></Customer> 
</accounts>
```

Expected output:

```
<accounts>
  <Customer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="text_type" name="customernumber">
    <value>101</value>
  </Customer>
</accounts>
```

Comment: Can you state what you mean by an empty tag? In your example, `value` is not actually empty, as it contains a space character. Additionally, it looks like you want the parent `Customer` element removed, but that is not empty either because as well as a space character, and a child `value` element, it contains attributes. Thanks

Comment: Actually it was a  typo as value doesn't contain space character(Edited input above) . It is empty and in that case I want to remove its corresponding parent customer element, Kindly suggest how to achieve using XSLT